# GNU make recompiles despite using object files

Tags: gnu-make

I have recently switched from Cmake to GNU make just to learn something new. In my Makefile I have it set so it will create object files and link them but every time I call make instead of just recompiling the ones that have changed it re-compiles every single one.

My Makefile

```
# Output directory of the *.o files
ODIR = obj
# Compiler flags
FLAGS = -std=c++17 -w -Wfatal-errors
LINKER_FLAGS = -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_mixer

#dependencies for output:
output: animation.o Asset_Manager.o Collision.o Engine.o Entity_Manager.o Entity.o Map.o Texture_Manager.o main.o
    g++ $(ODIR)/*.o -o game $(LINKER_FLAGS)
    ./game

#object files

animation.o: src/animation.hpp src/animation.cpp
    g++ -c src/animation.cpp $(FLAGS) -o $(ODIR)/animation.o

Asset_Manager.o: src/Asset_Manager.hpp src/Asset_Manager.cpp
    g++ -c src/Asset_Manager.cpp $(FLAGS) -o $(ODIR)/Asset_Manager.o

Collision.o: src/Collision.hpp src/Collision.cpp
    g++ -c src/Collision.cpp $(FLAGS) -o $(ODIR)/Collision.o

Engine.o: src/Engine.hpp src/tank.hpp src/Engine.cpp
    g++ -c src/Engine.cpp $(FLAGS) -o $(ODIR)/Engine.o

Entity_Manager.o: src/Entity_Manager.hpp src/Entity_Manager.cpp
    g++ -c src/Entity_Manager.cpp $(FLAGS) -o $(ODIR)/Entity_Manager.o

Entity.o: src/Entity.hpp src/Component.hpp src/Entity.cpp
    g++ -c src/Entity.cpp $(FLAGS) -o $(ODIR)/Entity.o

Map.o: src/Map.hpp src/Map.cpp
    g++ -c src/Map.cpp $(FLAGS) -o $(ODIR)/Map.o

Texture_Manager.o: src/Texture_Manager.hpp src//Texture_Manager.cpp
    g++ -c src/Texture_Manager.cpp $(FLAGS) -o $(ODIR)/Texture_Manager.o

main.o: src/main.cpp
    g++ -c src/main.cpp $(FLAGS) -o $(ODIR)/main.o

# Release Build
release:
    g++ -std=c++17 -O3  -s -DNDEBUG \
    ./src/*.cpp -o game_release \
    $(LINKER_FLAGS)
    ./game_release

# Recipes for the a spicy meatballs

run:
    ./game

run_release:
    ./game_release

clean:
    rm $(ODIR)/*.o game
```

Why does this recompile everything when make is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are breaking the [second rule of makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/):

```
Map.o: src/Map.hpp src/Map.cpp
        g++ -c src/Map.cpp $(FLAGS) -o $(ODIR)/Map.o
```

This rule says "if you want to build a file `Map.o` then here's a recipe that will do that".  But you've not told the truth here because that recipe does NOT build `Map.o`, it builds `$(ODIR)/Map.o`.  So the next time make runs it sees, "oh, I need the target `Map.o` but it doesn't exist, and here's a recipe that will create it, I will run it!" but yet again the recipe doesn't build `Map.o`.